Pip install to specific directory and include dependencies
I have a package I need but it has conflicts with another package that I use. This newer package that I need is not needed globally so I want to install it in a specific directory.
I have found the --target option for pip install but that doesn't seem to download all its dependencies in the target directory. Is there any way to do this?

It is customary to use virtual environment for local installations.

You should never be installing packages globally anyway. Use virtualenvs.

@AKX "Never" is a rather strong word.

@Jeyekomon Fair. The only package you should install globally is pipx. ;-)

To my surprise, it was hard to find a duplicate which says simply "use virtualenv" but like the other commenters here, that is my recommendation.
